# Visual studio 2015 application tab not showing in properties with unity generated solution

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, properties

I want to change the .net target version of a class library I created to version .Net35 since this is the only version supported by the unity generated solution. Only when I want to change this the application tab is not showing as shown in the picture.

[image]

I already added the unity option for adding project properties in tool as shown below

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this application tab is not showing? Is it just not possible with a unity generated solution?  Is there another way to change the .NET target version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a windows universal app just cannot target a lower framework and that you need to make a classic desktop c# app to be able to target lower.

If you are working with Unity like me you have to do this is a specific way like explained in : https://unity3d.com/partners/microsoft/porting-guides to make it work with UWP aps.